# gnuplot plotting multiple errorbars depending on first column

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with the following format: 
col1: plot[0-9]+
col2: x
col3: y
col4: delta

For example:

```
plot0, 1, 1, 2
plot1, 1, 2, 2
plot0, 2, 2, 1
plot1, 2, 3, 2
```

I am trying to plot a yerrorbars for each plotX of the first column with separated legend and color.

A none scalable example would be:

```
plot 'ex.dat' using 1:2:3 with yerrorbars, 'ex1.dat' using 1:2:3 with yerrorbars
```

Comment: I don't fully understand. What have you tried so far? In your case, `plot "Datafile.dat" u 2:3:4 w yerrorbars` should do the job. But I guess you haven't fully described your goal or problem. Do you want the data from each plot1, plot2, ... with its own color? Please show your code and plot result and explain what you actually would like to have.

Comment: I want to have, in the above example, 2 plots with 2 labels and colors. Like if I had 2 separated files plotting them with plot 'ex0.dat' using 1:2:3 with yerrorbars, 'ex1.dat' using 1:2:3 with yerrorbars

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? The color of the datapoint+yerrorbar is taken from the first column via the function `GetPlotNo(n) = int(strcol(n)[5:])`.
The second plot command is actually plotting a dummy outside of the range just to get the colors of the legend right. If you need the datapoints of each plot1, plot2, ... to be connected, this might get a bit more complicated.

**Code:**

```
### color of datapoints depending on a column
reset session
set colorsequence classic 

$Data <<EOD
plot0, 1.0, 1, 2
plot1, 1.1, 2, 2
plot0, 2.0, 2, 1
plot1, 2.1, 3, 2
plot2, 1.2, 3, 2
plot0, 3.0, 3, 1
plot1, 3.1, 4, 1
plot2, 2.2, 5, 1
plot2, 3.2, 4, 1
EOD

set datafile separator ","
set xrange[0:4]
set yrange[-1:7]

GetPlotNo(n) = int(strcol(n)[5:])

plot \
    $Data u 2:3:4:(GetPlotNo(1)+1) w yerrorbars pt 7 lc var lw 2 notitle, \
    for [i=0:2] -999 w lp pt 7 lc i+1 lw 2 title sprintf("plot%i",i) noautoscale
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Actually, if you want the lines to be connected it requires a small modification. Add/exchange the following lines and the lines of each plot will be connected.

```
set datafile missing NaN
plot \
    $Data u 2:3:4:(GetPlotNo(1)+1) w yerrorbars pt 7 lc var lw 2 notitle, \
    for [i=0:2] '' u (i==GetPlotNo(1)?$2:NaN):3:(GetPlotNo(1)+1) w lp pt 7 lc var lw 2 title sprintf("plot%i",i)
```